# Access chrome driver devtools in Selenium Grid 4 alpha 6,

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-grid, wdio-v6

I have a selenium grid 4 set up and have a local code which runs test cases that access chrome devtools (e.g. performance, Loading size, etc)

I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Is this even possible? there isn't much documentation for this. Or if there is, I dont understand them.